# What is the Entropy of Android's Dot Password System?

Tags: security, math, cryptography, statistics

How many *permutations* of the androids dot login system are possible?   I know for a fact the solution to this lies in Discrete Math,  specifically [Permutations Without Repetition](http://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html),  If your answer doesn't use permutations or combinations you are incorrect.

The length of passwords is between 4 and 9 dots,  There are a total of 9 dots to permute though.  so my initial equation is:

```
9P4+9P5+9P6+9P7+9P8+9P9
```

However,  I know this equation is incomplete because it does not take into consideration all of the rules.  Each dot is distinct because of is position so if you assign a number to each dot as follows:

```
123
456
789
```

The password "1397" is impossible,  if you attempt to use this password you will in fact have entered in "1236987" because the numbers in-between are automatically selected.  Another equation needs to be created to account for these limitations and then subtract off from my nPr equation above.

This [link](http://beust.com/weblog2/archives/000497.html) has a great video of someone using the android login.  It also goes into greater detail into the rules.  The math on that page is completely incorrect,  he is not even close to a real solution.

Comment: I think that 1397 is not actually impossible, just really tricky.

Comment: Nope, I just tried playing with my own phone.  It IS impossible.  It will select the dot even if you carefully pass over it.

Comment: Interesting problem. Since I don't own an android-based phone, one question about the rules: you can pass through an already-used dot, but does that affect the password? e.g. are 1254, 12514, 125124, and 125214 all considered distinct passwords, or are they the same (since all of them hit 1254 for the first time in the same order)?

Comment: I know nothing about Android, but this question seems sooo cool! :P

Comment: You guys rock,  I like this problem too.

Comment: @Tyler McHenry, You can never hit the same dot twice, even if your line or finger passes through it again.  12514 is not distinct from 1254.

Comment: This seems like a Project Euler question. Love it.

Comment: 9! isn't that large.  This is probably solvable just by brute force enumerating all the possibilities.

Comment: I think it is much larger than 9!.  You could brute force all possibilities but math is sexy and carpal tunnel is not.

Comment: I did brute force it, and the answer is only slightly greater than 9!.  I put the program I used to brute force it in my answer along with some demonstrations that my intuitions about a couple of things were valid.

Comment: Sorry I don't buy it.   You have to model it with math.

Comment: In my opinion, attempts to model this with relatively simple equations involving additions and subtractions of permutations will fail.  The problem can't be simplified in that fashion.

Comment: Its much larger than 9, since [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,5], [1,2,3,6], [1,2,4,5], [1,2,4,5,6], [1,2,4,7], [1,2,4,7,8], [1,2,4,7,8,9], [1,2,4,8], [1,2,4,8,9] and [1,2,4,9] are all possible and all begin on the 1.  The permutations are quite a bit larger, but certainly more finite than some might think.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is only a partial answer.  The only relevant starting dots are 1, 2, and 5.  For dots 1 and 2, you can generate a pattern equivalent to starting at any of the other dots (other than 5) with a simple rotation transformation.  This means if you can enumerate all the patterns starting at 1 and 2 you can count all the patterns starting at any number other than 5 by multiplying by 4.

The paths starting at 5 are a different case.  You can count all of them by counting all the paths that start with 5->1 and 5->2 and multiplying by 4 since you again can generate all the other possible paths with a simple rotation transformation.

So, a way to enumerate the paths would be...

(All paths starting at 1 + all paths starting at 2 + all paths starting with 5->1 + all paths starting with 5->2) * 4

Again, the numbering system, for easy reference:

```
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
```

For this first move:

From 1 -> 2, 4, 5, 6 and 8 are accessible.

From 2 -> 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, and 9 are accessible (basically just not 8 or itself).

From 5 -> 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, and 9 are accessible.

For moves after that it gets really interesting.

For example, 1537 is a valid password.  1539 is not.

Here succinctly, are the rules:

No dot may be part of the path twice.  If a dot is not part of the path and it is exactly crossed over by a transition, it becomes part of the path between the source dot and destination dot.

Here are some sample paths:

- 2->3->1->8 is allowed.
- 1->3->2->5 is not allowed because 2 is not part of the path when 1->3 goes exactly over 2, so the path becomes 1->2->3->5 whether you want it to or not.
- 1->2->3->7 is not allowed because 3->7 crosses over 5 and 5 is not already part of the path.
- 1->5->3->7 is allowed.  5 is ignored in 3->7 because it is already part of the path.

This program:

```
class LockPattern(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        if (len(args) == 1) and hasattr(args[0], '__iter__'):
            args = tuple(args[0])
        if len(args) > 9:
            raise TypeError("A LockPattern may have at most 9 elements.")
        self._pattern = ()
        for move in args:
            if not self.isValidNextStep(move):
                raise TypeError("%r is not a valid lock sequence." % (args,))
            else:
                self._pattern = self._pattern + (move,)
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._pattern)
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._pattern)
    def isValidNextStep(self, nextdot):
        nextdot = int(nextdot)
        if (nextdot < 1) or (nextdot > 9):
            raise ValueError("A lock sequence may only contain values from 1 "
                             "to 9 and %d isn't." % (nextdot,))
        if len(self._pattern) <= 0:
            return True # Any dot is valid for the first dot
        if len(self._pattern) >= 9:
            return False
        if nextdot in self._pattern:
            return False # No dot may be visited twice
        prevdot = self._pattern[-1]
        dotpair = tuple(sorted((prevdot, nextdot)))
        if dotpair == (1,3):
            return 2 in self._pattern
        if dotpair == (1,7):
            return 4 in self._pattern
        if dotpair in ((1,9),(2,8),(3,7),(4,6)):
            return 5 in self._pattern
        if dotpair == (3,9):
            return 6 in self._pattern
        if dotpair == (7,9):
            return 8 in self._pattern
        return True
    def isValidLockSequence(self):
        return 4 <= len(self)
    def newSequenceAddDot(self, nextdot):
        if not self.isValidNextStep(nextdot):
            raise ValueError("%d is not a valid next dot for the sequence." % (nextdot,))
        newseq = LockPattern()
        newseq._pattern = self._pattern + (nextdot,)
        return newseq

def genAllPatterns(starting = LockPattern()):
    if starting.isValidLockSequence():
        yield starting
    for dot in xrange(1,10):
        if starting.isValidNextStep(dot):
            for result in genAllPatterns(starting.newSequenceAddDot(dot)):
                yield result

print reduce(lambda x, p: x+1, genAllPatterns(), 0)
```

Generates an answer of 389112.

It also validates my previous intuitions:

```
lsts = tuple(((p, list(genAllPatterns(LockPattern(p)))) for p in ((1,), (2,), (5,1), (5,2))))
[(x[0], len(x[1])) for x in lsts]
-> [((1,), 38042), ((2,), 43176), ((5, 1), 7352), ((5, 2), 8708)]
sum((len(x[1]) for x in lsts)
-> 97278
97278 * 4
-> 389112
```

Answer (score 2):

The key is to notice that once you have visited any two dots, you can reach any other dot that you desire without moving through any dot that you have not already visited. So once you pick two starting dots (in order), then you can choose the rest of your password at will, in any order you wish. (This is because "knight's moves" are allowed, at least according to the page you linked)

So, excluding the 'starting two' dots, the number of remaining 2-7 digit tails are 7P2 + 7P3 + 7P4 + 7P5 + 7P6 + 7P7. There are 56 potential starting two-digit heads because there are 5 moves you can make from any corner dot, 7 from any edge dot, and 8 from the center dot. So the total number of unlocking patterns would be 56 * (7P2 + 7P3 + 7P4 + 7P5 + 7P6 + 7P7) = 766 752.

If this is wrong, it's probably because I am missing some knowledge of the rules of this system.

Comment: I think you are on the right track.  I'll have to spend some time to verify this a bit better.  Can anyone else verify this?

Comment: If you visit dots 1 and 8 you cannot visit dot 2, so your premise isn't correct.  Also, if you visit dots 2 and 7 you cannot then visit dots 1, 3 or dot 9.  You are not even correct after 3 dots.  If you visit 123, you cannot visit 7.

Comment: Then I must not be understanding rules, because according to your statement in the comments to the question, the sequence 182 is equivalent to the sequence 1812, which is legal. Similarly, 271 = 2721, 273 = 2723, 1237 = 12327. If that's not correct, then let me know what rule prevents this.

Comment: 1812 isn't legal.  The system turns any movement from 8 to 2 into a movement from 8 to 5 to 2 if 5 is not already a part of the path.

Comment: To clarify - 1812 isn't legal because it is exactly equivalent to 182 (revisits of dots that are already part of the path are completely ignored) which isn't legal.  The system turns any movement from 8->2 into a two part movement from 8->5->2 if 5 is not already a part of the path.  Once 5 is in the path, 8->2 becomes a possible transition.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so first off let me start by saying that omnifarious appears to be correct. What can we do with math. I would agree with him when he says that there are indeed only 3 cases to be concerned with. 1,2 and 5.

The OP wants some sort of elegant counting formula, which I'm doubtful exists for a problem like this. When you use all 9 dots you're finding Hamiltonian paths, which if this was a complete graph would be very easy to count (it's not). Because each of the three cases is unique, you're going to enumerate through all of them in order to find the total number of paths.

Let's take a look at the first case, beginning in a corner. You have four choices for a corner, then you have 5 choices for your next square. Now you'll quickly see that our formula expands rather quickly, because we have 5 choices and we have to split those 5 choices into 2 sets.

Moving to an middle side square, will have the same choices regardless of which one you move to. As opposed to moving to 5 which will give us many more options, already our formula is:

4*(4*(6)+1*(7))

Then we have to break the 6 and 7 options into further groups. If we move to a side square, then we can now move to two side squares, three corners and one middle square. Our formula then becomes:

4*(4*(2*(5)+3*(3)+1*(7))+1*(7))

Then we have to start solving for if we had moved to the middle square and I'm going to stop here. Finding Hamiltonian paths is NP-complete, albeit we're just counting them. But there aren't any properties here that we can take advantage of for an elegant solution. It's a graph theory problem and it's one that involves brute forcing the solution, as has been previously done by Omnifarious.

I'll try to explain why you're intuition is wrong, you say that:

"I know for a fact the solution to this lies in Discrete Math, specifically Permutations Without Repetition, If your answer doesn't use permutations or combinations you are incorrect."

Unfortunately you don't know this for a fact, because you don't know of a formula (unless you can show me a rigorous non-constructive proof). The fact is that a permutation or a combination means that when you have n items, you can pick any item at any iteration. Now you can put restrictions on the number of items you can pick and at what items you can pick at certain iterations. But what you can't do and expect an elegant solution is make picking certain items affect which items you can pick next. Which is exactly what this question is doing and why there isn't some nice formula using combinations and permutations.

In short the formula you're looking for doesn't exist, but Omnifarious did find the correct answer.

Comment: Thank you.  I was nearly certain that it wasn't really possible to come up with an easy formula, and I knew it was because what choices were valid changed depending on which choices you picked previously, but I didn't know how to articulate it clearly.  You articulated it quite clearly.

Answer (score 2):

Omnifarious was definitely accurate in his posting - there are 389,112 combinations. I posted a HUGE thing about the whole process of determining this algorithm, along with a text file listing every single combo from 1-9 length (which seems to be possible, from what I could tell on my girlfriend's phone). The link to this content is this: http://bit.ly/hEHcBJ

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if anyone still cares, but this is a graph path counting problem. There are 9 nodes, so create a 9 x 9 matrix (each row is a from node, each column a to node). If node n connects to node m, set (n,m) and (m,n) both to 1. Do this for all connections. Leave the rest zero. This is called the adjacency matrix. Raise this matrix to the number of lines in the pattern, and add all entries. This is the number of permutations. If anyone cares, i'll post some python code (on my phone or i'd post it now)

```
import numpy as np
paths = [[1,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[4,5],[4,6,7],[5,6,7,8],[7,8],[7],[8],[]]
m = [[0 for i in range(0,len(paths))] for j in range(0,len(paths))]

for i in range(0,len(paths)):
    for j in paths[i]:
        m[i][j] = 1
        m[j][i] = 1

for row in m:
    print row

[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]

adj = np.matrix(m)

adj.sum()
40

(adj**2).sum()
200

(adj**6).sum()
107648
```

My answers do not match those given by other people above, so i also wrote a graph traversal simulation for the graph in question. The simulation's answers (due to exhaust) match the answers from the adjacency matrix calculation. I also worked out the first two (one edge and two edges) by hand and got the same answers (40 and 200). Note that i am assuming that you can visit the same vertex repeatedly (i.e. 1->2->1->2...).

My graph:

```
0 - 1 - 2
| X | X |
3 - 4 - 5
| X | X |
6 - 7 - 8
```

Comment: Playing with my phone now, and realized that 0->5, etc are also allowed (i.e. my graph is wrong). My computer is off and i'm heading out of town for the weekend, so i can't fix it. Just update the path list for the actual allowed paths. The math is still correct.

Comment: Playing with my phone, and found that 1->2->1 style paths are not allowed. So it is not a strict graph traversal as the graph changes during traversal. It may still be calculable using matrices, though. Depends on the exact rules (never had a droid before)

Comment: Resurrecting this: We don't need to think of the graph as changing: we're just interested in paths, not walks. See my answer.

Comment: Ah, the graph *does* change, because things like 1 -> 4 -> 0 -> 2 are allowed (normally you can't jump from 0 to 2, but now we can since 1 is already used).

Answer (score 1):

**edit**: Nope, I'm wrong. The graph changes, because while in general things like 1 -> 3 aren't allowed (you'd have to go through 2 first), you *can* do things like 2 -> 5 -> 1 -> 3: The 1 -> 3 edge becomes available since 2 has already been used in the path.

I wrote a program to account for that and got the same 389,112 as Omnifarious (and I then realized my program was doing the same thing as his).

<s>I became curious about this: Fairly confident that it's 139,880. Like Jim said, this can be modeled by a graph. Raising an adjacency matrix to a power doesn't work because it counts paths with repeats, but you can just BFS through the graph:</s>

```
nodes = range(1, 10)

edges = {
    1: [2, 6, 5, 8, 4],
    2: [1, 4, 7, 5, 9, 6, 3],
    3: [2, 4, 5, 8, 6],
    4: [1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 8, 7],
    5: [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    6: [3, 2, 1, 5, 7, 8, 9],
    7: [4, 2, 5, 6, 8],
    8: [7, 4, 1, 5, 3, 6, 9],
    9: [8, 4, 5, 2, 6],
}

def num_paths(length):
    q = deque([node] for node in nodes)
    paths = []
    while q:
        path = q.popleft()
        if len(path) == length:
            paths.append(path)
            continue
        for node in edges[path[-1]]:
            if node not in path:
                q.append(path + [node])
    return len(paths)
```

And then just add the number of paths of lengths 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9.

```
>>> sum(num_paths(i) for i in range(4, 10))
139880
```